# Why did Alex's house have an dumbwaiter?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone-3

In [*Home Alone 3* (1997)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119303/), why did Alex's house have a dumbwaiter? What kind of house has a dumbwaiter?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to think the house shouldn't have a dumbwaiter? They definitely exist, so why shouldn't Alex's house have one?

Answer (score 0):

Dumbwaiters are not all that uncommon especially in larger houses. The house in Home Alone 3 is one such larger house with multiple floors and an attic. I don't see it as much of a stretch of the imagination to see why the house might have one.

Dumbwaiters are also featured fairly often in film. Two examples I can think of immediately are [*Jurassic World*](https://www.cbr.com/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdoms-best-easter-eggs/) and [*Annabelle Creation*](https://bloody-disgusting.com/movie/3452885/heres-one-annabelle-creations-scariest-scenes-made/).

In these examples, the dumbwaiter is used as a plot device, and it provides the same function in Home Alone 3. It provides an opportunity for some comedy, and is also likely a callback to the laundry chute gag from the first Home Alone - another home feature which is fairly common in larger homes.

#### Home Alone 3 - dumbwaiter gag

#### Home Alone - laundry chute gag